# Extract values array using indices

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indices

I need to extract certain values from a multidimensional array that are not subsequent.

```
import numpy as np    
A = np.array([[[ 0.,          4.,          0.        ],
               [ 0.19230769,  4.03846154,  0.        ],
               [-0.4,         4.8,         0.        ],
               [ 2.,          1.,          0.        ]],

              [[ 1.2,         3.4,         0.        ],
               [ 2.11538462,  4.42307692,  0.        ],
               [ 0.,          4.,          0.        ],
               [ 3.6,         1.8,         0.        ]],

              [[ 1.8,         3.1,         0.        ],
               [ 3.17307692,  4.63461538,  0.        ],
               [ 0.,          4.,          0.        ],
               [ 4.,          2.,          0.        ]]])
```

For every 4x3 block I want to extract an arbitrary row

For instance the following elements:

```
A[0,2,:]
A[1,1,:]
A[2,1,:]
```

So basicly the rows`B = [2,1,1]`, which would give me:

```
[-0.4         4.8         0.        ]
[ 2.11538462  4.42307692  0.        ]
[ 3.17307692  4.63461538  0.        ]
```

How to do this efficiently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use ["advanced indexing"](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing):

```
In [99]: A[[0,1,2], [2,1,1], :]
Out[99]: 
array([[-0.4       ,  4.8       ,  0.        ],
       [ 2.11538462,  4.42307692,  0.        ],
       [ 3.17307692,  4.63461538,  0.        ]])
```

Here the indexing arrays are

```
ind1 = [0, 1, 2]
ind2 = [2, 1, 1]
```

and since `ind1` is indexing the first axis of `A` and `ind2` is indexing the second axis, and the third axis is getting fully sliced (with `:`), the resulting array, `result`, has the same shape as `ind1` and `ind2` -- i.e. `(3,)` -- plus the shape of the fully sliced axis, which is also `(3,)`.  Thus, `result.shape` is `(3, 3)` and

```
result[i, j] = A[ind1[i], ind2[i], j]
```

for `i = 0,1,2` and `j = 0,1,2`.